# For a FireFox Overlay how do you specify what Gecko/FireFox version(s) to apply it to?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Have a pluggin that is installed as part of an app, the pluggin needs to use different overlays depending on what version of FF is being used as it modifies the interface.

I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Bundles to specify different files but this only seems to cover which OS/bitness.

Is there a way to specify that an overlay only applies to particular versions of the UI?

ie. This works for FF3.6 and earlier but breaks FF4

```
<overlay id="myOverlay"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <dialog id="commonDialog" onload="commonDialogOnLoad(); myLoad();"
        ondialogaccept="myAccept(); return commonDialogOnAccept();">
```

This is aimed at the Domain Login and the FTP Login dialogs, so an idea on making it more specific could help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, but I think you can accomplish this effect using flags in your `chrome.manifest` file. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#Manifest_flags

Comment: Seems to do the trick, `appversion>=4.0` on a new overlay file for FF$ and  `appversion<=3.*` on the old file.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the answer by MatrixFrog is correct, you can use flags in your chrome.manifest file. However, you better consider the fact that your code breaks Firefox 4 a warning - this approach should not be used, it is likely to break browser functionality. Also, what if a second extension tries to do the same thing? You should **extend** built-in functionality, not overwrite it. Your goal is apparently to run your own code when the common dialog loads. Please consider the following approach:

```
<overlay id="myOverlay"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
        window.addEventListener("load", function()
        {
            // Your code here
        }, false);
    ]]></script>
</overlay>
```

This solves two problems. For one, you no longer need to override the existing handler for the "load" event - addEventListener allows registering as many event handlers as you want, unlike onload attribute/property. The other problem: you were adding a function myLoad() to the global namespace of the common dialog. If Firefox code or some other extension decides to use the same function name in future there will be trouble. The code above completely avoids this problem by using an anonymous function - there can be no naming conflicts.

Comment: I see your point, though a bit confused in the detail.  Shouldn't that still be within the dialog tag to apply only to the commonDialog rather than at the top level?

Comment: Script tags are treated in a special way - you can simply place them inside an overlay and they will execute when the overlay applies. No need to put them inside the `<dialog>` tag explicitly, that's where they will end up anyways. Side-note: Normally the only thing you should do when this script executes is registering a listener for the `load` event. Doing anything else before the `load` event is likely to cause breakage (e.g. other overlays won't apply any more), this is a common mistake.

Comment: Tried to add event listener for 'load' and when it wasn't working right for 'loadComplete' which also didn't work as I expected.  Need to run some further changes after the standard setup - the order the onload event is called is important.  (perhaps I should raise as another question)

Comment: Yes, probably worth a new question - this isn't really related.